# Changing Autocomplete value using react-hook-form (Material-UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have two Autocomplete fields, my goal is to change the value of the second field by the value of the first field.

The problem I face is when my trying to send the new value to the "setValue" function nothing happens the state form changing, but the autocomplete field shows the old value.
In this sand box:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-carson-84dxp?file=/src/Form/Components/UserCountry.js

you can see my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at console when you change `user_name` field, you can see materialUI warning in the console which says:

*Material-UI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.*

it's reason is that your `user_country`'s value by default is `undefined` and material consider this field as uncontrolled field, it means material will take the control of `user_country` value. To solve the problem you have two solutions:

1- Defining your form by `defaultValues` options like this:

```
const methods = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    user_name: null,
    user_country: null
  }
});
```

2- Sending `null` as value to `AutoComplete` when it doesn't have any value, like this:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={`user_country`}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      options={countries}
      onChange={(event, item) => {
        onChange(item);
      }}
      value={value || null}
      ...
    />
  )}
/>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-surf-8dmo7) You can see your form which updates `user_country` whenever you change `user_name` field.